# Query data from another data frame for new column in r

Tags: r, database, merge

Alright, I am new to data frame management and manipulation in R and am having trouble querying and adding information to my data frame for analysis. I have 3 data frames 
df1

```
dput(Year   HNo Month   Day County  ST  ResState    ResZIP
2005    218050003   10  8   MIDDLESEX   CT  CT  6037
2005    218050003   10  10  MIDDLESEX   CT  CT  6037
2005    218050008   9   1   NEW LONDON  CT  CT  6355
2005    218050008   9   10  NEW LONDON  CT  CT  6355
2005    218050008   9   12  NEW LONDON  CT  CT  6355
2005    218050008   9   16  NEW LONDON  CT  CT  6355
2005    218050008   9   23  NEW LONDON  CT  CT  6355
2005    218050008   9   28  NEW LONDON  CT  CT  6355
2005    218050008   10  12  NEW LONDON  CT  CT  6355
2005    218050008   10  18  NEW LONDON  CT  CT  6355
2005    218050008   10  22  NEW LONDON  CT  CT  6355
2005    218050008   11  11  NEW LONDON  CT  CT  6355
)
```

df2

```
dput(FID    County  STATE_NAME  STATE_FIPS  CNTY_FIPS   FIPS    AREA
590 Litchfield  Connecticut 9   5   9005    929.3449
591 Hartford    Connecticut 9   3   9003    742.8998
593 Tolland Connecticut 9   13  9013    411.904
594 Windham Connecticut 9   15  9015    522.058
642 New London  Connecticut 9   11  9011    706.352
647 Fairfield   Connecticut 9   1   9001    661.2935
651 Middlesex   Connecticut 9   7   9007    379.362
652 New Haven   Connecticut 9   9   9009    623.3514
)
```

df3

```
dput(zip    city    state   latitude    longitude   fips
6001    Avon    CT  41.7897 -72.86431   9003
6002    Bloomfield  CT  41.8328 -72.72642   9003
6006    Windsor CT  41.87964    -72.73427   9003
6010    Bristol CT  41.68225    -72.93365   9003
6011    Bristol CT  41.79178    -72.71883   9003
6030    Farmington  CT  41.79178    -72.71883   9003
6034    Farmington  CT  41.79178    -72.71883   9003
6045    Manchester  CT  41.79178    -72.71883   9003
6049    Melrose CT  41.79178    -72.71883   9003
)
```

I want to add columns to df1 as follows: Use County to match with df2 and add the appropriate AREA. Then use ResZip to match with df3(zip) to get the appropriate latitude and longitute. I know I need to change column names where needed, but not sure how to execute those queries. I am used to Access, but can't translate to R. I have tried merge, but I get too much additional information. Thanks so much for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could give `dplyr` a try. The `verbs` (actually functions) are easy to undersand and follow.  That being said, the sample data frames provided seem to have no matchings.

```
library(dplyr)
res1 = left_join(df1, df2 %>% select(County, AREA),
                 by=c("County"="County"))
res2 = left_join(res1, df3 %>% select(zip, latitude, longitude),
                 by=c("ResZIP"="zip"))
res2
#    Year       HNo Month Day    County ST ResState ResZIP AREA latitude longitude
# 1  2005 218050003    10   8 MIDDLESEX CT       CT   6037   NA       NA        NA
# 2  2005 218050003    10  10 MIDDLESEX CT       CT   6037   NA       NA        NA
# 3  2005 218050008     9   1 NEWLONDON CT       CT   6355   NA       NA        NA
# 4  2005 218050008     9  10 NEWLONDON CT       CT   6355   NA       NA        NA
# 5  2005 218050008     9  12 NEWLONDON CT       CT   6355   NA       NA        NA
# 6  2005 218050008     9  16 NEWLONDON CT       CT   6355   NA       NA        NA
# 7  2005 218050008     9  23 NEWLONDON CT       CT   6355   NA       NA        NA
# 8  2005 218050008     9  28 NEWLONDON CT       CT   6355   NA       NA        NA
# 9  2005 218050008    10  12 NEWLONDON CT       CT   6355   NA       NA        NA
# 10 2005 218050008    10  18 NEWLONDON CT       CT   6355   NA       NA        NA
# 11 2005 218050008    10  22 NEWLONDON CT       CT   6355   NA       NA        NA
# 12 2005 218050008    11  11 NEWLONDON CT       CT   6355   NA       NA        NA
```

Comment: Great, thanks. Is there a way to match on two columns? Say by=c("Month"&&"Day"="Month"&&"Day") ?

Comment: @tjr, Yes, there is. Suggest to post it as separate question with representative sample data though.

Answer (score 2):

This will work except in the data you provided there were no matching Fips between df2 and df3. If you have an understanding of SQL then you can go into the sql view in access and convert that and use sqldf in R. next if you use the dput function and copy that output it makes it much easier for people to help you out.

```
library(sqldf)        
df1 = structure(list(Year = c(2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 
2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L), HNo = c(218050003L, 
218050003L, 218050008L, 218050008L, 218050008L, 218050008L, 218050008L, 
218050008L, 218050008L, 218050008L, 218050008L, 218050008L), 
    Month = c(10L, 10L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    11L), Day = c(8L, 10L, 1L, 10L, 12L, 16L, 23L, 28L, 12L, 
    18L, 22L, 11L), County = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("MIDDLESEX", "NEWLONDON"
    ), class = "factor"), ST = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "CT", class = "factor"), 
    ResState = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "CT", class = "factor"), ResZIP = c(6037L, 
    6037L, 6355L, 6355L, 6355L, 6355L, 6355L, 6355L, 6355L, 6355L, 
    6355L, 6355L)), .Names = c("Year", "HNo", "Month", "Day", 
"County", "ST", "ResState", "ResZIP"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))

df2 =   structure(list(FID = c(590L, 591L, 593L, 594L, 642L, 647L, 651L, 
652L), County = structure(c(3L, 2L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("Fairfield", 
"Hartford", "Litchfield", "Middlesex", "NewHaven", "NewLondon", 
"Tolland", "Windham"), class = "factor"), STATE_NAME = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Connecticut", class = "factor"), 
    STATE_FIPS = c(9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L), CNTY_FIPS = c(5L, 
    3L, 13L, 15L, 11L, 1L, 7L, 9L), FIPS = c(9005L, 9003L, 9013L, 
    9015L, 9011L, 9001L, 9007L, 9009L), AREA = c(929.3449, 742.8998, 
    411.904, 522.058, 706.352, 661.2935, 379.362, 623.3514)), .Names = c("FID", 
"County", "STATE_NAME", "STATE_FIPS", "CNTY_FIPS", "FIPS", "AREA"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))


df3 = structure(list(zip = c(6001L, 6002L, 6006L, 6010L, 6011L, 6030L, 
6034L, 6045L, 6049L), city = structure(c(1L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("Avon", "Bloomfield", "Bristol", 
"Farmington", "Manchester", "Melrose", "Windsor"), class = "factor"), 
    state = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "CT", class = "factor"), 
    latitude = c(41.7897, 41.8328, 41.87964, 41.68225, 41.79178, 
    41.79178, 41.79178, 41.79178, 41.79178), longitude = c(-72.86431, 
    -72.72642, -72.73427, -72.93365, -72.71883, -72.71883, -72.71883, 
    -72.71883, -72.71883), fips = c(9003L, 9003L, 9003L, 9003L, 
    9003L, 9003L, 9003L, 9003L, 9003L)), .Names = c("zip", "city", 
"state", "latitude", "longitude", "fips"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))


sqldf("Select tbl1.*, tbl2.Area,tbl3.latitude,tbl3.longitude 
                    from df1 tbl1
                    inner join df2 tbl2 on upper(tbl1.County) = upper(tbl2.County)
                    inner join df3 tbl3 on tbl2.FIPS = tbl3.fips")
```